# how to cancel pending graphql when destroy page / component in vue / nuxtjs?

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo, nuxtjs

I want to cancel all pending graphQL when I am changing the page. I have tried with apollo skipAllQueries, skipAllSubscriptions, skipAll not working. Does anyone know how to do it?
[image: example]

Comment: Hello have you find you problème ? because i have same probleme thanks for you response :D